# How to design properly the logic of getting data from DB in the case of pagination (JAVA)?

Tags: java, pagination

Ok, I am building an app in client and it needs to take data from DB. The app won't take all data from DB all at once but based on the pagination.

It has a simple textbox for user to enter text and a Button to search data.

> Requirements:
>
> -If the system already downloaded the data from a certain pageNo, then it won't call to server again.
>
> -Each time it successfully called to server it needs to remember the pageNo, so that next time when user searching for that exact term it
> will search for `pageNo=pageNo+1` cos we searched for `pageNo`
> already.

So here is what i did:

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> wordPageNoHashMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
   @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        int pageNo=0;
        if(wordPageNoHashMap.containsKey(word)){
                    
            pageNo=wordPageNoHashMap.get(word); //note: page no only increase if found result
        }
        else{
            pageNo=1;
            wordPageNoHashMap.put(word, pageNo);
        }
        callToDB(word,pageNo);
   }
});

public void resultFromDB(ServerResult result){
   int pageNo=result.getPageNo();
   String word=result.getWord();
   List<String> textResult=result.getResult();
   if(textResult!=null && textResult.size()>0){
        pageNo++;
        wordPageNoHashMap.put(word, pageNo);
       //show data here
   }
   else{
       //show err here
   }
}
```

I putting `pageNo++` at the result not at the time we call.

Am i designning it ok?

or

Can u do a better design?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my understanding is correct, for a search query I will retrieve a reasonable number of records from the DB (say 500) and store it in something like a [PagedListHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html) and set the per page data to whatever number you want(say 20).

Now I have two options, when the user clicks next I will simply call the [nextPage()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html#nextPage%28%29) and retrieve the data set. (This might be applicable for infinite loading)

Or if the user is clicks on a particular page number (conventional pagination), I will pass on the page number to the [setPage()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html#setPage%28int%29) method and retrieve the elements from that page.

I have used the PagedlistHolder example to make it easy for you to understand. You may use any similiar Class if available, or you can write one.

I think this achieves your objective of not hitting the DB for the same set of data.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: the page shouls go from pageNo 1 to 2 , 3... Just increase by 1 & I don't want to download too many at the first time since user can just found the right text in the 1st time they get data. ALso the 1st data is always more relevant than the latter one

Comment: But that is a tradeoff again. You need to tread the middle path. Hitting the DB for every page is a bad design IMHO. I find it better to load the first five or ten pages and load the rest only if required. And I don't see 10 pages as too many records.

Comment: agree, 10 records r just in this example, in real world it will be 30 records

Comment: So what have you decided?

Comment: at this monment i still think i am doing ok as stated in my question unless someone got a better one.